# Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.13'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, libv8

I recently upgraded to the latest version of Mavericks and it seems to have broken a few of my Rails 3 app. When I try to run a bundle install, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.11.8.13), and Bundler cannot
>   continue.
>
> Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.13'` succeeds before bundling.

I tried to clear the cache and running bundle install from some other SO answer, but wasn't able to fix it. I also tried downloading and installing the gem from https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/107, but it did not work.

Finally, I've tried `gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.13'`, but am still getting the exact same error when I run bundle install again.

Any advice?

Thanks.

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :production, :staging do
    gem 'pg'
end

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.1"
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.2.2'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'annotate', ">=2.5.0.pre1"
end


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'therubyracer'#, :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

Comment: add to Gemfile the line `gem 'libv8', :git => 'https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8.git', :branch => '3.11'`. and issue `bundle install`.

Comment: `brew link --overwrite postgresql` seem to do the trick since it was an issue with my postgresql.